# Переход между окнами пролистыванием

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Доброго времени суток!
   Изучаю работу с segue между двумя ViewController ами. Хотел узнать, как использовать вызов segue при пролистывании справа на лево или наоборот? К чему segue необходимо привязать (ViewController, View, Button)? Тип должен быть Custom? И что такое Segue Module (при выборе Custom)?
   Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может лучше использовать UIPageViewController?

**Другой способ это:**

Проверить, что пользователь сделал нужный свайп справа на лево и презентовать второй ViewController.

**1) А презентацию Вы можете сделать кастомную, т.е. как будет появляться второй ViewController.**

**2) Либо использовать стандартный presentviewcontroller, когда производит swipe:**

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Чтобы прийти на предыдущий ViewController, то используйте тоже самое, только с другим Identifier, или это

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**3) Либо использовать pushviewcontroller:**

```
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Чтобы прийти на предыдущий ViewController, то используйте тоже самое, только с другим Identifier, или это

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

***PS: segue в этом случае лучше не использовать (если это вообще возможно).***

Swipe вы можете проверить с помощью Swipe Gesture Recognizer

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Если надо сделать простой переход между 2мя ViewController, то достаточно связать кнопку на первом ViewController со вторым ViewController. Тип указывайте в зависимости от желаемого результата. Custom, если я правильно помню, для ручной обработки Segue.

Comment: переход простой. но вызывать он должен не по нажатии а при пролистывании от края экрана